# Why is my NSSMutableString potentially insecure?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablestring

Why is my `NSMutableString` potentially insecure? I searched for this but couldn't find anything.

```
int hour = [number intValue] / 3600; 

NSMutableString *time = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];

if (hour < 9) {
    [time appendFormat:@"0"];
    [time appendFormat:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d:", hour]];
}
```

What's wrong with it? This is the first time I've seen this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. It would help if you explained why you think this string is "potentially insecure".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my string potentially unsecure in my iOS application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961363/why-is-my-string-potentially-unsecure-in-my-ios-application)

Comment: Also similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428325/issue-with-code-format-string-is-not-a-string-literal

Comment: You searched for this? Really? [Googling "objective-c potentially insecure"](http://www.google.com/search?ie=utf8&oe=utf8&q=objective-c+potentially+insecure&nfpr=1) brings up a first page full of helpful-looking links for me. Can you elaborate on the warning you're getting and why previous questions didn't help you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this:

```
[time appendFormat:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d:", hour]];
```

To this:

```
[time appendFormat:@"%d:", hour];
```

The `appendFormat` method is expecting you to pass a string with format, not an `NSMutableString`. This screenshot shows it:

[image]

Comment: This is, of course, the answer. But you might want to explain it a bit. :)

Comment: Thank you so much, i know now where was mistake ; )

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question asked here but it looks like the provided code is attempting to reinvent existing format string options.

`[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:", hour]` will print a two digit integer value with leading zeros.

Comment: True, but I think this should be a comment, seeing that it doesn't answer the question.