# Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)

Tags: objective-c, compiler-warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my string potentially unsecure in my iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961363/why-is-my-string-potentially-unsecure-in-my-ios-application)

New compiler warning since upgrading XCode to 4.6:

[image: Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)]

Smallest example demonstrating the warning on both of the final lines:

```
  for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSString *res = [testInstance generate:i];
    NSString *desc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TestData: %d", i];
    STAssertNotNil(res, desc);
    STAssertNotEquals(@"", res, desc);
  }
```

I looked at other questions which concern this warning but they stem from programmers unnecessarily using `stringWithFormat:` - here I want a dynamic assert description which changes per iteration but not per check.

I can pass the format string and data into the Asserts but then I have to maintain the descriptions independently.

**How can I avoid this warning if I require the formatting of a description is prior to using it in a log message or assert call?**

Comment: It should be noted that the `stringWithFormat` will be evaluated every iteration, whereas if you placed the format string inside the asserts it would be evaluated only if the assertion fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem are the non-literal format strings in the assertions. Change them to:

```
STAssertNotNil(res, @"%@", desc);
STAssertNotEquals(@"", res, @"%@", desc);
```

Format strings are a common security issue. When they are not visible to the compiler it cannot check them. In your case they've been hidden in `desc`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? How is it a security issue if the compiler can't check them?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Printf style format strings are a common security exploit. When the format string argument is not constant an attacker can inject a forged format string that writes arbitrary data to memory locations outside of the buffer used for printing. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string